# How do I enable font anti-aliasing in Wine?

Tags: wine, font-rendering, antialiasing

Fonts in some Wine applications (Word 2007 for example) are heavily aliased. How do I turn on anti aliasing for Wine applications?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest way is through `winetricks`

```
mkdir ~/bin
cd ~/bin
wget http://winetricks.org/winetricks
chmod +x ./winetricks

winetricks fontsmooth-rgb
```

In newer version of `winetricks` the command to use is

```
winetricks settings fontsmooth=rgb
```

There are other LCD pixel orders available. You can read about them and the rest of the impressive winetricks feature list on [its WineHQ site](http://wiki.winehq.org/winetricks).

Comment: winetricks is also available through apt

Comment: @Roland it is but I can't attest to which version it is. Though the logic doesn't apply to something as simple as this, `winetricks` is one of those things you want to keep as recent as possible if you're following install guides that use it heavily.

Comment: The wine ppa has updated versions :D, so you can use that as an additional option ^^

Answer (score 7):

Just adding details to [Oli's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/29556/74172) for those who need it: what `winetricks settings fontsmooth=rgb` actually does is creating and importing a registry file with the following content:

```ini
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"FontSmoothing"="2"
"FontSmoothingGamma"=dword:00000578
"FontSmoothingOrientation"=dword:00000001
"FontSmoothingType"=dword:00000002
```

Once you saved it as `fontsmoothing.reg` you can import it with:

```bash
wine regedit fontsmoothing.reg
```

Comment: why isn't it the default?

Comment: As of today there are several options for `fontsmooth`, namely `bgr`, `disable`, `gray` and `rgb` .  Default values are `"FontSmoothing"=2` , `"FontSmoothingGamma"=dword:0x0` , `"FontSmoothingOrientation"=dword:0x1`, `"FontSmoothingType"=dword:0x1`, so only `"FontSmoothingGamma"` and `"FontSmoothingType"` get updated in the option **fontsmooth=rgb**

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method with no relation on a temp file:

```
$ env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/<prefix> wine reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v FontSmoothing /t REG_SZ /d 2 /f

$ env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/<prefix> wine reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v FontSmoothingGamma /t REG_DWORD /d 0x578 /f

$ env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/<prefix> wine reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v FontSmoothingOrientation /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f

$ env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/<prefix> wine reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v FontSmoothingType /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
```

Verify that the changes are applied successfully:

```
$ env WINEPREFIX=~/.wine/<prefix> wine reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" | grep FontSmoothing
```